# Using arrays and templates in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

in an attempt to understand templates better (and thus be able to read basic documentation on c++), I am trying to perform basic operations on arrays as templates. Below is code that defines a function template for averaging an array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
double GetAverage(T tArray[])
{
    T tSum = T(); // tSum = 0
    int n=tArray.size();
    for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex < n; ++nIndex)
    {
        tSum += tArray[nIndex];
    }

    // Whatever type of T is, convert to double
    return double(tSum) / n;
}

int main ()
{
  array<int,5> data={0,1,2,3,4};
  cout << GetAverage(data);
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

For some reason, as you will see, the compiler runs into issues when dealing with properties of the array, such as array.size(), all within the defining code of a function. I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'GetAverage'
   cout << GetAverage(data);
      ^~~~~~~~~~
note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'T *' against 'array<int, 5>'
  double GetAverage(T tArray[])
     ^
```

How can I refer to the properties of an object when defining a function which takes in said object as input (all the while using the language of templates)?

Comment: That is because `T tArray[]` as function parameter is incorrect, or the same as `T* tArray`. You need `T tArray`, or `const T& tArray`.

Comment: array is a STL container, it's not a C array so you don't need the []

Comment: ah - thanks! what a simple mistake.

Comment: Once you figured that out, you can get the average as `auto avg = std::accumulate(begin(data), end(data), 0.0)/data.size();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[C++11 array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a STL container, not a C array thus the following is incorrect:

```
T tArray[]
```

A correct version of the above could be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
double GetAverage(T tArray)
{
    // More compact version as suggested by juanchopanza
    auto avg = std::accumulate(begin(tArray), end(tArray), 0.0)/tArray.size();
    return avg;
}

int main ()
{
  array<int,5> data={0,1,2,3,4};
  cout << GetAverage(data);
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/RyPqOr

if you intend to use something more sophisticated you might have to use a struct or a class since functions don't have partial specialization.

Comment: `int tSum = 0;` contains the invalid assumption that the array can be summed into an int.   Much better in C++11 anyway, would be `auto TSum = tArray[0]`  (after checking size, of course.) then adding tArray[1 thru N]

Comment: I agree, and the template parameter was useless anyway with the previous code

Comment: If you want to restrict it to actually being `std::array`, then do `template<class T, size_t N> double GetAverage( std::array<T,N> t_array )`  (and consider taking const ref)